# MVC Model Object losing value

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

ok... I'm Stumped

```
    public ActionResult addSite(SiteViewModel aModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            siteID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            aModel.siteId = siteID;

            AddSite2Azure();

            return RedirectToAction("manageProfile", "User");
        }
        else { return View(aModel); }
    }


    private void AddSite2Azure()
    {
        EmPmSiteEntity aSite = aEnty.AssetRegistry.CreateSite(new EmPmSiteEntity()
        {
            UserId = aUserId,
            Id = aModel.siteId,
            Name = aModel.siteName,
            ZipCode = aModel.siteZip,
        });
    }
```

When Debugging, aModel.siteID has a guid at the end of my actionResult. But when we get to the next method, the value of aModel.siteID is "null"

Comment: You are most likely setting the wrong `aModel`. Do you want `this.aModel` instead? Or do you intend to pass the `aModel`from `addSite` to `AddSite2Azure`?

Comment: SiteViewModel aModel = new SiteViewModel(); is at the top of my code... aModel is not being re-initalized, and all the other aModel Values (name & zip) are being retained. This is code from the controller for the SiteViewModel, I shouldnt have to pass the model around inside the controller

Comment: Top of your code where? If you mean member variable then addSite's aModel will hide it.

Comment: ..... wow, totally missed my method overload... Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean _when we get to the next method_. You don't pass the instance of `aModel` that was posted to the method, so all your referring to is a new instance so of course it will be null

Answer (score 1):

It appears as though you have two scopes for `aModel` - one at the class level (not shown in your code), and one at the method level (passed as a parameter to `addSite(...)`).

You're setting the value of the method-level variable in `addSite()`. To use this value in `AddSite2Azure()`, either pass the method-level `aModel` to `AddSite2Azure()`, or set the class-level `aModel` in `addSite()` by using `this.aModel`.